# Derivative determinant function of a matrix

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Basically this is the problem I am trying to solve, I differentiated it but am pretty sure it isn't correct, used the formula:
$$\frac{f(I+h) - f(I)-Ah}{h}$$
where A is the derivative and I is the 2 by 2 identity matrix.
substituting everything in and solving I got A = 2, however this doesn't make sense to me, can anyone tell me where I have gone wrong and how to do it correctly?

Edit: apologies here is the correct link to my question:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsYHa.png

Comment: I don't understand your question? Your link doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Sorry I uploaded the wrong question, I fixed it now.

Comment: Try computing the derivative of $f(a, b, c, d) = ad-bc$.

Comment: with respect to which variable?

Comment: You need to compute the total derivative, not partial.

Comment: how does one do that? I haven't learnt that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sketch:** Suppose
\begin{align}
h =
\begin{bmatrix}
h_{11} & h_{12}\\
h_{21} & h_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
such that $|h_{ij}|<\varepsilon$, then we see that
\begin{align}
\det(I+h)-\det(I) =&\ (1+h_{11})(1+h_{22})-h_{12}h_{21}-1\\
 =&\ 1+h_{11}+h_{22}+h_{11}h_{22}-h_{12}h_{21}-1\\
=&\ \operatorname{Tr}(h)+\det(h).
\end{align}

Note that $\operatorname{Tr}(\cdot)$ is linear. So, we try
\begin{align}
\frac{\det(I+h)-\det(I)-\operatorname{Tr}(h)}{\|h\|} =&\ \frac{\det(h)}{\|h\|} \\
=&\ \frac{h_{11}h_{22}-h_{12}h_{21}}{\sqrt{h_{11}^2+h_{12}^2+h_{21}^2+h_{22}^2}}.
\end{align}

Finally, note that
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{h_{11}h_{22}-h_{12}h_{21}}{\sqrt{h_{11}^2+h_{12}^2+h_{21}^2+h_{22}^2}}\right|\le 2\varepsilon. 
\end{align}

Comment: Sorry, what does Tr(h) mean?

Comment: trace of a matrix.

Comment: So what is the derivative then? I follow what you have written, but for that to be the derivative wouldn't you need to take the limit as h goes to 0 and I'm not sure if that can be simplified so there is no h terms on the bottom.

Comment: Also why are you allowed to subtract tr(h) since the definition of the derivative  is $$ \frac{det(I+h)-detI)}{h}$$ I can't figure out why you subtract tr(h)

Comment: what you found to be less that epsilon isn't the derivative.

Comment: it is the derivative minus tr(h)/h

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative#The_total_derivative_as_a_linear_map

Comment: Alright, I still don't get it, but thank you for trying.

Comment: oh wait, so is tr(h) the derivative of the equation?

Comment: tr() is the derivative.

Comment: thank you, sorry I am a bit thick haha

Comment: I have a problem, if the derivative is equal to the trace of the matrix, if we were to keep x_11 and x_22 at 0 and only move the other variables then this would imply the directional derivative is 0 and the determinant isn't changing, however as we increase x_12 and x_21 the determinant would decrease not stay constant.

Answer (score 0):

Let $s$ be a scalar variable, $H$ a matrix, and $I$ the identity matrix.

Then by l'Hopital's Rule
$$\eqalign{
\frac{d\det(I+sH)}{ds}\Bigg|_{s=0}
 &= \lim_{s\to 0} \frac{\det(I+sH) - \det(I)}{s} \\
 &= \lim_{s\to 0} \frac{\big((1+sh_{11})(1+sh_{22})-s^2h_{12}h_{21}\big)-1}{s} \\
 &= \lim_{s\to 0} \frac{s(h_{11}+h_{22})+s^2(h_{11}h_{22}-h_{12}h_{21})}{s} \\
 &= \lim_{s\to 0} \frac{s\operatorname{Tr}(H) + s^2\det(H)}{s} \\
 &= \lim_{s\to 0} \;\operatorname{Tr}(H) + s\det(H) \\
 &= \operatorname{Tr}(H) \\
}$$
Although the Laplace expansion of the determinant is shown for a $2\times 2$ matrix, the final result holds for an $n\times n$ matrix.

The expansion of the numerator will have **many** more terms arranged in powers of $(s^1\,s^2\,\ldots\,s^n)$, however all but the first will disappear upon taking the limit.